# Working with webresource in asp.net, application running on localhost but not on web server

Tags: .net, asp.net, captcha, webresource.axd

I am building an application where i am using a web resource for implementing [captcha](http://www.mondor.org/captcha.aspx). 
When i runs this application on my localhost, it run successfully but when i tries running it live then no image gets displayed in captcha.

[This](http://www.vaibhavjain.info/%28S%28lpklscjgjkrfzmee3pblen55%29%29/Web%20Pages/Authentication/Login%20Management/Login.aspx) is my live application where no image is being displayed. But it is running successfully on localhost.

What can be the problem ?

I have added the refrence to this captch control on my system. But i dont know whether i need to register that dll on server also and if yes then how ??

GoDaddy is my hosting server.

Comment: Not sure, because your link is broken, but one thing I can tell from your URL and which is considerd to be bad practice is the use of spaces in URL. I'd first have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

have you added

```
<add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha"/>
```

to your live site web.config file httphandlers section?